# ajax jsonp Get request skips scripts at time of call but fires them later

Tags: ajax, jsonp

I'm running an ajax/jsonp/Get request. Using fiddler I can see a proper response ( jsonpCallBack({"GetMetadataResult":{"TotalPages":"20"}}); ) but at the time of the request the ajax call just  returns not running either the  success, error,complete, or callbackFnt script. Later, after my function completes, the  ajax success script is run. Not sure what I’m doing wrong.

```
function getRequest( url, data )
{
    var ajaxRequest = undefined;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible

    //"Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    var response =  $.ajax( {
        "url": url,
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "jsonp",
        "data": data,
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "jsonpCallback": "jsonpCallBack",
        "success": function ( r )
        {
            return r;
        },

        "complete": function ( r )
        {
            for ( var i = 0; i < r.count; i++ )
            {
                return r;
            }
        },
        "error": function ( xhr )
        {
            return false;
        }            
    } );

    return true;
}

function jsonpCallBack( r )
{
    return r;
}
```

Comment: It looks like ajax is sending the message but not waiting for the response before it returns. When it gets the response it then runs the success script, but by then the rest of my code has run.

Comment: Should also mention that async:false  does not help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is doing anything wrong, but the design is.  There is no such thing as synchronous JSONP as you've found out.  From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

"Cross-domain requests and `dataType: "jsonp"` requests do not support synchronous operation"